# Order by size postgres bytea

Tags: postgresql, bytea

I have images stored in a postgresql 9.1 database table in bytea fields.
I want to do a query to order them by size and show their size.
I need this because there are some big images that are causing delay issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select length(the_image_column) as the_size
from t
order by 1 desc
```